# Is there a way to simulate the communications costs in tensorflow-federated?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am working on optimizing the communication costs in Federated Learning. Therefore, I need to simulate realistic network delays and measure communication overhead (the communication between the clients and the server). Is it possible to do that with TFF? Is there a realistic networking model for communications in Federated Learning setting?

Answer (score 2):

Introducing network latency or delays  in the execution stack is not something that TFF currently supports out of the box.

However, architecturally this is absolutely possible. One example of a recent contribution that addresses a similar request is the [`SizingExecutor`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/d5a88f5131424872672f89a667712916df4dc622/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/executors/sizing_executor.py#L80), which measures bits passed through it on the way down and up in the execution hierarchy. Placing a `SizingExecutor` immediately on top of each executor representing a client, then, measures the bits broadcast and aggregated in each federated computation run through this execution stack; this implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/d5a88f5131424872672f89a667712916df4dc622/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/executors/executor_stacks.py#L294), and is in fact exposed in the public API.

Your desire is not entirely dissimilar to the sizing executor, and the sizing executor may serve your purpose directly, if you take total bits ber round as the metric you are trying to optimize. If however you would rather be examining other aspects of distributed computation (e.g. random data corruption) you may imagine doing so by implementing similar functionality to the sizing executor, though one could also imagine doing this at the computation level (a client chooses at random whether to return its true result or a corrupted version of its result).

I think from a design perspective, TFF would prefer any new executors to *leave the semantics of the computations they are executing unchanged*, and would steer towards either simply measuring properties like bits per round, or introducing any corruptions into the computation or algorithm directly, rather then in execution of these computations. The kind of corruption or delay a client can choose to introduce is effectively arbitrary; [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/d5a88f5131424872672f89a667712916df4dc622/tensorflow_federated/python/research/targeted_attack/attacked_fedavg.py#L145) is an example of a recent research project attempting to attack the global model by inserting malicious updates on certain clients. The same approach could be used, I imagine, to simulate any desired network property (e.g., some clients sleep, some send back corrupted updates, etc.).

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there pytorch implementation function similar to SizingExecuter ?